# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use BufferedReader while ServletInputStream is in use

Tags: java, http, post

Can Java experts help me on this issue, I'm geting the error below

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use BufferedReader while ServletInputStream is in use

I'm calling a REST service url to post some data using a server side java code, not through a browser.

```
 try{
    String urlLocation = "http://myserver/james/dev/hello.nsf/services.xsp/test";
    URL url = new URL(urlLocation);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false); 
        connection.setDoOutput(true); 
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ); 
        //connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-length", Integer.toString(content.length())); 
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
        out.writeBytes (getXML());
        out.flush ();
        out.close ();
        connection.disconnect();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 

        String line;
        while( (line = in.readLine()) !=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            } 
        in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error from 2nd try statement");
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.toString();
        }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: Please find the stack trace

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use BufferedReader while ServletInputStream is in use
 at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.servlet.XspCmdHttpServletRequest.getReader(XspCmdHttpServletRequest.java:1373)

 at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.servlet.LCDAdapterHttpServletRequest.getReader(LCDAdapterHttpServletRequest.java:324)
 at 

com.ibm.xsp.http.FileUploadRequestWrapper.getReader(FileUploadRequestWrapper.java:703)
at 

javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getReader(ServletRequestWrapper.java:251)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be this line

```
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

I noticed the BufferedReader is not being instantiated, you are reusing an instance variable `in`.

I copied your code and just changed it to this, and I can make multiple requests without any problem.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: I tried removing as you suggest, Still throwing the same error message. Any other thoughts

Comment: Can you try adding a finally and closing all connections ?

Comment: Added finally.Looks like the connection is returning null, let me go to debug mode and see why the connection is null.
finally{
   System.out.println("executing finally");
   if (connection !=null){
    System.out.println("DISCONNECTING");
    connection.disconnect();
   }else{
    System.out.println("connection is null");
   }
  }

Comment: No luck...removed the finally for now...I see that the call reached the end point as it print status messages on the server.
I have a feeling that it's due to Sync nature of Java calls as the chances it executes the next line of code before the server code finishes it's execution.
Any other thoughts...

Comment: @user2986018 try what I just added now ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same error occurred while testing with an empty request body in a POST request. When provided with an empty JSON object {} in the request body, the code runs as expected.